# Equivalent R and Python with a DataFrame

Tags: python, r, dataframe, subset

I'm stuck with an equivalence of code between R and Python.

Code in R

```
library(datasets)
data <- airquality
data2 <- data[data$Ozone < 63,]
```

I download the file of airquality and use pd.read_csv() function for obtain the .csv file into Python. But I don't know how obtain this equivalent line `data[data$Ozone < 63,]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
data2 = data.loc[data["Ozone"] < 63,:]
```

This should do the trick.

- `data["Ozone"] < 63` returns an index where the condition is verified
- `data.loc[index, :]` returns a copy of the dataframe `data`, for all columns `:` on the given `index`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Worked perfectly.